# Create matrix representing linear function with ones and zeros

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization

I have a linear function where the slope is variable :

y = slope * x + b

What is the algorithm for create a matrix NxN filled of zeros, and ones represents where the linear function is passing through ?

Example :

For a slope of 10° and matrix size is 5x5 :

I need to get this :

```
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
```

For a slope of -35° I must have :

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

I have to do this with matrix of 2000x2000

Comment: See algorithms for line drawing (there is a lot).